# Usage of deprecated font command `\rm'! (KOMA-script)

Tags: koma-script

I am using the `scrreprt` documentclass and I keep getting the warning:

```
Usage of deprecated font command `\rm'!(scrreprt) You should note, that in 1994 font command `\rm' has(scrreprt) been defined for compatiblitiy to Script 2.0 only.
```

Using a **MWE**, it comes out that the warning is generated from the commands `\tableofcontents{}` , `\listoftables{}` and `\listoffigures{}`

While digging a little bit further, my **scrreprt.cls** already contains `\scr@DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}`

Does any one knows how to get rid of this warning?

**Update:** Here is a the MWE:
Remark: I just found out that using the package fncychap is causing the warning. I use it to generate decoration rectangles at the beginning of chapters:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[11pt,headings=small,fleqn]{scrreprt} % highest level is chapter

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %To add a rectangle at the beginning of each chapter
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % for English text only

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{1}

%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
%%------------List of Tables----------------------
\listoftables{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\listoffigures{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}

%maintain Roman numerals on the previous page
\clearpage%set pagination to Arabic
\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\chapter{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 'Don't use `\rm`': I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, really.

Comment: Can you post your MWE? When I make one I get no such warnings.

Comment: The package `fncychap` (which provides the ugliest chapter styles I've ever seen) uses those obsolete commands.

Comment: @egreg True, the package `fncychap` is the one using those commands. Just for the defense of the package,  saying that it provides the ugliest chapter styles is a personal opinion.

Comment: @user2536125 Yes, it's personal opinion. My judgment stems from both aesthetics and TeX code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning is caused by `fncychap`, which must use `\rm` for the `Glenn` style. I would just not use that package. If you really want it, add

```
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large\rmfamily}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sffamily}
```

after loading `fncychap`. These are copied from the `fncychap` manual, but with `\rm` replaced by `\rmfamily` and `\sf` replaced with `\sffamily`.

Additional notes:

- `fontsize=11pt` is the default for KOMA classes, so you don't actually have to specify it.
- With the `scrbook` class you get the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` commands. The first sets up roman numbering of pages, the second switches to arabic.
- To add the float lists to the ToC, add `listof=totoc` as an option to the document class. This does not add the ToC itself to the ToC, but `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}` will do that.
- By the way, `\tableofcontents` and `\listof..` doesn't take an argument, so the brace pairs are unnecessary.
- As I switched from `scrreprt` to `scrbook` in the code below, I added  `oneside` and `openany` to the class options, as that is what `scrreprt` does by default. Naturally, if you want margins set up for twosided printing and chapters to start on recto pages, remove those.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[
  headings=small,
  fleqn,
  oneside,
  openany,
  listof=totoc,
  toc=listof]{scrbook} % highest level is chapter

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %To add a rectangle at the beginning of each chapter
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large\rmfamily}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sffamily}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for English text only

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

%%-----------Table of Contents------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
%%------------List of Tables----------------------
\listoftables
%%------------List of Figures----------------------
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I absolutely agree, but I like the rectangles enclosing the chapter title so I do want to use the package `fncychap`. If you find a workaround, please update your answer and i will be glad to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @user2536125 I updated a minute ago.

Comment: @clemens Thanks! I meant to check if KOMA had something similar, but I forgot  ... Will edit my answer.

Comment: @clemens Is there some option for adding the ToC to the ToC? (Which the OP apparently want.)

Comment: @clemens Only thing I can think of was if there was other stuff (listed in the ToC) before the ToC, so that you can see where you are in relation to those things. But yeah, not really necessary.